# Make route go out right gateway

Tags: networking, routes

I guess I just don't understand how routes work. My routing table has a route for `0.0.0.0` with a netmask of `0.0.0.0` with the lowest metric of all other routes. Doesn't that mean none of the other routes matter, since that encompasses every IP, and it was my understanding that the lowest metric wins?

Either way, by default, everything should route out the 10.236.35.52 interface, but I would like `64.233.0.0` with a newm with a netmask of `255.255.0.0` to route different interface than the default, interface 192.168.116.244. I tried making two routes for that path, one for the interface I want (192.168.116.244) with a lower weight (metric) and one for the default interface with a higher weight (metric). Hoping this would override the 0.0.0.0 route at the top. My logic might be completely wrong, in fact it probably is, because its not working. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Metrics are like a cost, the higher the metric, the more it costs, and you would like to pay less for the same product.

Comment: @RonMaupin So does that mean that nothing after the 0.0.0.0 matters. Everything will get caught by that rule? Since its the lowest weight and contains every IP?

Comment: What matters the most is the length of the match of the address to the network. A longer match will always win, regardless of the metric. The metric breaks ties. The `0.0.0.0/0` network matches everything, but it is the shortest match you can have, so it is the path of last resort for a packet with a destination that doesn't match anything else.

Answer (score 3):

> Doesn't that mean none of the other routes matter, since that encompasses every IP, and it was my understanding that the lowest metric wins?

No. Routes are considered in order according to the number of bits set to 1 in the netmask. For example, a route with a `255.255.255.255` (32 bits set to 1) netmask is very specific and has the highest precedence, since it only matches one IP. `0.0.0.0`, or `00000000000000000000000000000000` in binary, is your default gateways and has zero bits set to 1.

If multiple routes match, the route with the lowest metric will be used.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it sounds like my configuration should be correct to send `64.233.0.0` traffic out `192.168.116.244`?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see.